# How to display nested graphql object datatypes given mongoDB objectID?

Tags: mongodb, graphql

I am writing an app with GraphQL and mongoose. I created a function to get all bookings inside MongoDB. A booking object contains a reference to another object called Service. When I store a booking, it will store the associated service object as an ObjectID in MongoDB. When I make a query in graphql to get all the bookings, graphql does not services and their field types since graphql only receives an objectID. How can I fix graphql?

[image: Error message returned for graphql]

[image: All the bookings are inside the database but user is represented as an objectID]

[image: GraphQL datatype definitions]

[image: Resolver in question making the query]

[image: The graphql function declaration called createAppointmentBookings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a resolver for the serviceType in AppointmentBooking.

```
Query: {
  async getAppointmentBookings() {
    ...
  }
},
Mutation: {
  ...
},
AppointmentBooking: {
  serviceType: async(parent, args, ctx, info) => {
    // Here you will get the objectId from the parent that need to query services
    // This will call for every object inside the bookings
    // Assuming you are storing the objectID for the services in the key servicetype
    const serviceId = parent.serviceType;
    try {
      const serviceDetails = await Sevice.findByID(serviceID) ;
      return serviceDetails;
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm wondering is this the general design pattern for working with GraphQL and databases like MongoDB?

Comment: For any future reference, const serviceDetails = await Sevice.findByID(serviceID) is what worked as this method is called for each AppointmentBooking which holds its own serviceID.

Comment: https://medium.com/paypal-engineering/graphql-resolvers-best-practices-cd36fdbcef55. This blog post will give better understanding with the patterns,

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help!